# Assembly.GetAssembly(type) vs type.Assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I wanted to know what are the benefits, if any, to calling either of these methods, and why?
Are they functionally equivalent, or should I always be choosing one over the other?

Comment: They are essentially equivalent, only raising different exceptions if `type` is `null`.  (`ArgumentNullException` vs `NullPointerException`)  NPE's are generally useless and should always be prevented through null checks. Having it throw an `ArgumentNullException` for you seems like a much nicer alternative.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that as @JeffMercado pointed out, they are essentially equivalent and Microsoft just wanted to provide a method (`Assembly.GetType(type)`) and a property (`type.Assembly`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK they're functionally equivalent, however Assembly.GetAssembly(Type) is not available in the core-clr (Silverlight and the like)

You would get different errors based on whether or not your `Type` is null.  `Type.Assembly` will throw a NullReferenceException (naturally) whereas `Assembly.GetAssembly(Type)` would throw an ArgumentNullException.  Based on your code you might prefer one or the other.

EDIT: Looking at the source, for `Assembly.GetAssembly`:

```
public static Assembly GetAssembly(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    Module m = type.Module;
    if (m == null)
        return null;
    else
        return m.Assembly;
}
```

Whereas `System.Type.Assembly`:

```
public abstract Assembly Assembly {
    get;
}
```

If I recall correctly, the System.Type for runtime types are their own subclasses (or something like that) So I guess each one maybe overrides and simply directly returns an assembly reference.  Beyond that, I don't think there's any significant difference for you to worry about with your code beyond null handling which is up to you.  (Or if you're running the Core-CLR in which case you don't have Assembly.GetAssembly anyway so you *must*  use Type.Assembly)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation for `Type.Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly.aspx)

> If the current `Type` object represents a constructed generic type, this
>   property returns the assembly that contains the generic type
>   definition.
>
> For example, suppose you create an assembly named
>   `MyGenerics.dll` that contains the generic type definition
>   `MyGenericStack<T>`. If you create an instance of
>   `MyGenericStack<int>` in
>   another assembly, the Assembly property for the constructed type
>   returns an Assembly object that represents `MyGenerics.dll`

From the documentation for [Assembly.GetAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx):

> In order to call this method, you must have a `Type` object, which means
>   that the assembly in which the class is defined must already be
>   loaded.

Comment: Sounds exactly the same to me.  How could you call `myType.Assembly` if you don't have the type object loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why they're making a big deal out of the generic case for `Type.Assembly`, but they do seem to think it's important.

Comment: I read that as `MyGenericStack<int>` might technically not exist in `MyGenerics.dll`, and thus be created in somewhere else in code, to maintain a programmer's sanity, the type check points to the `MyGenericStack<T>` declaration's assembly.  Worthwhile to mention I suppose to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair The compiler creates a class called ``MyGenericStack`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]`` inside the assembly where you instantiate a `MyGenericStack<int>`, *NOT* the assembly which declares `MyGenericStack<T>`.  That means using `Type.Assembly` should return your assembly, not `MyGenericStack.dll`, but MS decided to change the behavior.